# Spring data jpa + joining 2 tables

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have 2 entity classes `Product` and `ProductAltID` with no `@OnetoMany` mapping defined between them.

I want to do something like this

```
select p from ProductAltid inner join Product pai
where p.id = pai.id
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried "select p from ProductAltId as p where p.id in (select pai.id from Product as pai)" ?

Comment: How can I achieve this from my repository level... I have 2 repositories created Like ProductRepository extends JpaRepository

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this method to the ProductAltId repository (choosing that one because the query returns ProductAltIds):

```
@Query("select pai from ProductAltId as pai " 
+ "where pai.id in (select p.id from Product as p)")
List<ProductAltId> findForAllProducts();
```

I switched the aliases around, they seem backward in your example.

Comment: this returns me the entire thing... but if I am doing'@Query("select pai from ProductAltId as pai where pai.itemCode=?1 " 
+ "where pai.id in (select p.id from Product as p)"
List<ProductAltId> findForAllProducts()'   it is throwing a org.springframework.dao
Class InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException

Comment: @user3439560: don't know. seems there are a lot of things that could cause that. fixed a missing paren in the annotation, btw.

Comment: I removed the entire thing and did a simple elect pai from ProductAltId as pai where pai.itemCode=?1 it still breaks

Comment: @user34395560: is the param right? you can use `select pai from ProductAltId as pai where pai.itemCode=:itemCode` and put an annotation @Param("itemCode") on the parameter.

Comment: yes Nathan... that is the way to do it.. apparently for some weird reason ?1 doesn't work